# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: How to inject properties

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins 2.19.4 with Pipeline: Declarative Agent API 1.0.1. How does one use readProperties if you cannot define a variable to assign properties read to?

For example, to capture SVN revision number, I currently capture it with following in Script style:

```

```
echo "SVN_REVISION=\$(svn info ${svnUrl}/projects | \
grep Revision | \
sed 's/Revision: //g')" > svnrev.txt
```

```

```
def svnProp = readProperties file: 'svnrev.txt'
```

Then I can access using:

```
${svnProp['SVN_REVISION']}
```

Since it is not legal to def svnProp in Declarative style, how is readProperties used?

Comment: Just to be clear, the above example script is from a Jenkinsfile and would be wrapped in a pipeline step "sh".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load properties from properties file and make them available throughout the job/pipeline - Jenkins declarative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754764/load-properties-from-properties-file-and-make-them-available-throughout-the-job)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `script` step inside the `steps` tag to run arbitrary pipeline code.

So something in the lines of:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                writeFile file: 'props.txt', text: 'foo=bar'
                script {
                    def props = readProperties file:'props.txt';
                    env['foo'] = props['foo'];
                }
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo env.foo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm using env to propagate the values between stages, but it might be possible to do other solutions.

Comment: Initially got this exception `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object` I was able to "whitelist" by going to "In-process Script Approvals" and `approving staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object` Now it works!

Comment: @P.Beatty I am seeing similar issue. Is it possible to mentioned whitelisting process in details. I am kind of lost, not sure where to start

Comment: Never mind found it "Navigate to jenkins > Manage jenkins > In-process Script Approval"

Answer (score 4):

The [Jon S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256112/4298200) requires granting script approval because it is setting environment variables.  This is not needed when running in same stage.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('A') {
      steps {
        writeFile file: 'props.txt', text: 'foo=bar'
        script {
           def props = readProperties file:'props.txt';
        }
        sh "echo $props['foo']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To define general vars available to all stages, define values for example in `props.txt` as:

```
version=1.0
fix=alfa
```

and mix script and declarative Jenkins pipeline as:

```
def props
def VERSION
def FIX
def RELEASE

node {
   props = readProperties file:'props.txt'
   VERSION = props['version']
   FIX = props['fix']
   RELEASE = VERSION + "_" + FIX
}

pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         echo ${RELEASE}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know we could mix them. Is there any doc on this?

Comment: In [Pipeline Concepts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#pipeline-concepts) you can find differences between declarative and scripted pipelines