# Assigning variables in a parallel step using Declarative Pipeline steps in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert my Scripted pipeline to a Declarative Pipeline and running in some basic (I think) issues.

```
    stage ('Deploy to Docker') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                "instance1" : {
                    environment {
                        containerId = sh(script: "docker ps --quiet --filter name=${fullDockerImageName}", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    }
                    steps {
                        ....
                    }
                }
            )
        }
   }
```

This causes the following Exception:

```
WorkflowScript: 197: Expected a step @ line 197, column 29.
                           containerId = sh(script: "docker ps --quiet --filter name=${fullDockerImageName} ", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Since I'm not allowed to do variable assigning inside a `steps {}` block, I moved it to an `environment {}` block, but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Any idea on how to set these kinds of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252552/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-how-to-inject-properties/42256112#42256112), you can execute arbitrary pipeline script inside a `script` step. So taking your example:

```
stage ('Deploy to Docker') {
    steps {
        parallel (
            "instance1" : {
                steps {
                    script {
                        env['containerId'] = sh(script: "docker ps --quiet --filter name=${fullDockerImageName}", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    }
                    ....
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gonna try that soon.

Is this intentional? I'm guessing it's the same with if-statements (can't seem to use those either in `steps`). Can't really find any documentation whether is was designed this way (and why) or if it's simply a feature-that-is-coming.

Comment: Yes, think this is intentional, i.e. there is a reason that they have added the `script` step. If you look here, https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps, there is some reasoning about this. I think the main reason for this "limitation" is that they are adding graphical editing of declarative pipelines, and thus there must be a limited set of constructs inside the `steps` section.