# How to subscribe to email notification in specific currently running Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins build running. Is there a way to subscribe to notification of just that build, that I am interested in?

I am not interested in other builds of the same job.

Can that be done in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put the emailext plugin inside a script step with if

I found some examples here: [How to do simple if-statements inside a declarative pipeline in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281200/how-to-do-simple-if-statements-inside-a-declarative-pipeline-in-jenkins)

2. You can use the when step