# Jenkins pipelineTriggers option crashes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cron, continuous-integration

Trying to use a cron-triggered build in a Jenkins declarative pipeline script:

```
options
{
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
    pipelineTriggers([cron('H 0 * * *')])
}
```

When run, throws this Exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid option type "pipelineTriggers". Valid option types: [buildDiscarder, catchError, disableConcurrentBuilds, overrideIndexTriggers, retry, script, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, timeout, timestamps, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, ws] @ line 30, column 3.
        pipelineTriggers([cron('H 0 * * *')])
     ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:238)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anyone know the correct syntax or a workaround for a cron trigger in pipeline script?

Answer (score 5):

From [JENKINS-37731](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37731), I see a cron used with the following syntax:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        cron('H/5 * * * *')
    ])
])
```

See for instance as an example the [`jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/Jenkinsfile`](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/blob/c0828af5b8bd428815e23537c808cd0267017013/Jenkinsfile#L4).

Since you are using a [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), you will need to inject those properties: see "[Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: How to inject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256112/6309)"

> You can use the `script` step inside the `steps` tag to run arbitrary pipeline code.

That is because [`pipelineTriggers` and `parameters` are excluded from job properties](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/commit/3b0271d4ac42d4343b72cda5ec2394910a165198), as seen in [`pipeline/modeldefinition/model/Options.groovy`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/f8a149286d08bc450243aa32479cdff45643446f/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/model/Options.groovy#L56)

```
public final static List<String> BLOCKED_PROPERTIES = ["pipelineTriggers", "parameters"]
```

Comment: That seems to be for a non-declarative pipeline script. Simply putting `properties(...` somewhere in a declarative script wont work.

Comment: @BadmintonCat Right: I have added the missing step (injection of those properties)

Comment: I see but still don't know how to use the injection with pipelineTriggers, since that is a function. Wondering if this gets fixed soon in Jenkins!

Comment: @BadmintonCat If you can inject properties, can you access then as environnment variable (WithEnv)? Or  `environment.withProperty()`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you do this using Pipeline Syntax:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H 4/* 0 0 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also , pollSCM defines a regular interval at which Jenkins should check for new source changes. If new changes exist, the Pipeline will be re-triggered. For example:

```
// every 15 minutes
triggers { 
  pollSCM('H 4/* 0 0 1-5') 
}
```

Comment: post is tagged as groovy

Comment: @JoePhillips: He wrote, "Trying to use a cron-triggered build in a Jenkins declarative pipeline script". Please check this link: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline Error output in groovy is expected.

Comment: @YgorThomaz Is it possible to use multiple triggers in the same jenkin file ? I have requirement to run build every hour and also for every commit. I understand I need to use pollScm and cron both but haven't had luck with it.